# term for when players go all-in and show hands

Tags: texas-hold-em

> Player A- 2000$  Player B- 870$  Player C- 2500$  if A bets 450$ and B goes all in with 870$ can C or A go all in?

Answer (score 1):

C can go all in, but if C just folds or calls, A cannot raise because he has not been raised. B's $870 is short of the required minimum raise to $900, and so it does not reopen the action to A (but of course it doesn't affect C's rights in any way).

Answer (score -1):

Yes, C and A can either simply call B or raise (up to all in) if they want.

Comment: As explained by Lee, the raise from B is not legal ( less than double the previous raise ) and as such, the game continues as if B just called ( although the call amount is updated to 870 ). If C were to call, A would not have the option to re-raise back.